# What does '@@' do on sqlplus prompt?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm not a PL/SQL developer but my current task at work needs me to go through a lot of them. I'm trying to learn it quick but oracle documentation seems tedious. So asking this question.

In one of the .sql script I seen,

installer.sql

```
@@pkgstringinteger.h
@@pkgstringinteger.sql
@@load_policy.sql
```

so what does this @@ do?

I know on sqlplus prompt if we have to execute any .sql file then we put @ at the start. e.g.

```
SQL>@load_policy.sql
```

But was wondering what would putting it twice would do? I tried to google but it was difficult to get answer to this peculiar question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@@foo.sql` does the same thing as `@foo.sql` (executes the commands in that file), but looks for the file in the same directory as the calling file.